# question on the greens function for 1st order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE

$xy' + 5y = x − 4x
^3$

I am trying to compute the greens function, but am having some difficulties

i) is the $a_1(t)$ in the greens function equal to there, as $a_1(x)=x$?

ii)in order to check my solution should I be able to plug in the particular solution $$y_p(x)=\int
G(x, t)g(t) dt$$
or do i need to use the general solution ?

Comment: @Moo yes that's correct

Comment: y_p(x) is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous ODE a1(x)Dy + a0(x)y =g(x) compute a particular
solution for
xDy + 5y = x − 4x
3
in the region 1 ≤ x ≤ 2, and then show explicitly (i.e. plug it in) that it
does indeed satisfy this ODE.

Comment: @Moo that's as much information as was given apart from the general outline of the greens function technique.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the homogenous solution, ie the solution to $xy'+5y=0$ are the constant multiples of $x^{-5}$. Therefore, the Greens function here is $G(x,t)=t^{5}x^{-5}$

Comment: but greens functions always have to have two values, one for x>t and one for x<t.

Comment: do you mean G(x,t)=+-t^5x^-5 ?

Comment: also shouldn't there be a 2 in the denominator ?